# SQLAlchemy 1.4 "operator does not exist" errors with pg8000

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pg8000

It seems that the previous versions we were on (SQLAlchemy 1.3.23) automatically coerced strings to the appropriate variable type for the query.  For example:

```
session.query(my_data).filter(my_data.the_date = '2022-07-01').all()
```

'2022-07-01' would be coerced to a date type automatically. Now I am getting a ton of of errors like the following

> operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone = character varying

I would like to avoid going through our code base and changing all of these cases by using date objects, etc... instead of strings.  I am surprised I am not find more on this issue.  Is there some setting in SQLAlchemy that allows strings to be coerced? Or maybe some other solution?

Comment: What is `my_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy 1.4+ requires pg8000 [version 1.16.6 or later](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html#change-493b1ad80e0643bcd7f28ccd453ca356) and that version of pg8000 also seems to have made some other breaking changes, apparently including the way that string literals are handled in comparisons to date/timestamp columns.

If you want to reduce the changes in your code to avoid those errors with SQLA 1.4 you might consider switching to `postgresql+psycopg2://`.